# Solving matrix equations with some Boundary Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

How can I solve a system of linear equations with some Boundary conditions, using Numpy?

**Ax=B** 
Where **x** is a column vector with, let's say **x1=0**.
For different iterations BCs are going to be different, so different variables of vector x going to be zero.
**[A]** and **[B]** are known.

Here is an example from my FEM course:
{F} Is the column vector of known values
[k] is the stiffness matrix with the known values
{U} is the displacement column vector where U1 and U3 are known to be zero, but U2 and U4 need to be found.

[image]

Here is an example:

[image]

This would result in these values:

[image]

Naturally this would reduce to the 2X2 matrix equation, but I because for different elements the BC would be different, I'm looking for some numpy matrix equation solver where I can let it know that some of the unknowns must be this certain value and nothing else.
Is there something similar to **np.linalg.solve()** with conditions to it?

Thank you.

Comment: linear equations with boundary conditions? is your system of equations underdefined? (i.e. is there a span of solutins?). please give the most simple example of A and B that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, updated

Comment: please provide some code (even if it is only input)...  a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). why not just invert the matrix as usual?

Comment: ha! Why not indeed!!! Thank you! But then I'd need to make a logic loop to see if one of the Us equal to zero and eliminate that particular row and column. Certainly doable, but is there an easier way? a predefined numpy function?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, sorry, no code. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Try sympy. Maybe that is you are looking for.

Comment: at least some data for k, U, and F? if k has full rank there will be one unique solution to this; no other choice for U will solve the equation... if k does not have full rank the story is different...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, updated. but I don't know what you mean by "full rank"

Answer (score 1):

the matrix `k` in your example is invertible. that means there is one and only one solution; you can not choose any of the `U`s. this is the solution:

```
import numpy as np

k = np.array(((1000, 0, -1000, 0),
              (0, 3000, 0, -3000),
              (-100, 0, 3000, -2000),
              (0, -3000, -2000, 5000)))

F = np.array((0, 0, 0, 5000))

U = np.linalg.solve(k, F)
print(U)
# # or:
# k_inv = np.linalg.inv(k)
# U = k_inv.dot(F)

# [ 5.55555556  8.05555556  5.55555556  8.05555556]
```

the same in sage:

```
k = matrix(((1000, 0, -1000, 0),
              (0, 3000, 0, -3000),
              (-100, 0, 3000, -2000),
              (0, -3000, -2000, 5000)))
F = vector((0, 0, 0, 5000))
U = k.inverse() * F

# (50/9, 145/18, 50/9, 145/18)
```